# Python Dataframe Expand Rows and Generate IDs

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe like this:

```
 name       quantity
   a           5
   e           4
   g           7
```

Expected output:

```
name            id
  a              1
  a              2
  a              3
  a              4
  a              5
  e              1
  e              2
  e              3
  e              4   
  g              1
  g              2 
  g              3
  g              4
  g              5
  g              6
  g              7
```

I would like to create IDs for each name. Regarding to each of their quantity, the ID will start from 1 and end when `id = quantity`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You could amalgamate `reindex` with `repeat` on your quantity column, and then use `cumcount+1` to get your desired outcome:

```
new_df = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df.quantity)).drop('quantity',axis=1)
new_df['id'] = new_df.groupby('name').cumcount()+1


  name  id
0    a   1
0    a   2
0    a   3
0    a   4
0    a   5
1    e   1
1    e   2
1    e   3
1    e   4
2    g   1
2    g   2
2    g   3
2    g   4
2    g   5
2    g   6
2    g   7
```

Try running each line at a time and check what we do. We are first repeating the amount of rows, based on the value in your quantity column. And then replacing the values in quantity using `cumcount()+1` after grouping by 'name'.